# Can an NPN transistor have its base connected to the same power input as the collector?

Tags: transistors, npn

All the tutorials I have seen on using an NPN transistor as a switch have base and collector attached to two different power inputs with two different resistors:

[image]

My question is, can the base just be connected to the same power input/resistor as the collector? Like so:

[image]

Comment: That's configuration acts like a diode.

Comment: ... and Vout will always be 0.7 V or so. Can you see why?

Comment: @Transistor by Vout you mean the voltage coming out of the transistor and say going into an LED?

Comment: What you have draw in the 2nd picture is a BJT with negative feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done (transistors are very flexible and can by used in a myriad of ways). It can be useful (mostly in ICs) as part of a 'current mirror' where you want 2 or more devices to run the same current.

In addition, a diode like this can be 'better' than a standard (e.g. 1N4148) diode with lower leakage (but worse breakdown V), and better 'ideal' (IC=Is*exp(-q.vBE/kT)) characteristics for common use in analog multipliers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is commonly called a "diode connected transistor".

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing has very little practical use. A transistor in the normal configuration is used as a switch. Usually a small or weak control signal on the input is used to switch a larger current through the load - in this case R<sub>C</sub>. When the transistor is switched on (by applying a voltage to V<sub>in</sub> the collector voltage, V<sub>out</sub> will drop almost to zero.

If you wanted to switch an LED, for example, you would wire it in series with R<sub>C</sub>.

Your modification is feeding some current from R<sub>C</sub> to the base. This will turn the transistor on and V<sub>out</sub> will drop towards zero and stay there. You have lost the ability to switch so you might as well replace the transistor with a piece of wire between C and E.

Comment: I have tried this on a breadboard, with a LED being between Rc and Vout. Connecting Base to the same port as `vcc (after the transistor)` momentarily blinks the LED. Is my transistor busted?

Comment: Probably, yes. The base emitter junction is like a diode and needs current limiting. By connecting it directly to Vcc without a base resistor you will have run a very high current through the base and exceeded its ratings.

Comment: This is a very common configuration in integrated circuits. It is also a component of a current mirror. So I disagree that it has "little practical use".

Comment: @Transistor I'm using an arduino to supply power to the breadboard. funny thing is when I connect base to 3.3v of aruduino while connecting collector to 5v+resistor the LED turns on just fine, but when I also connect base to 5v+resistor it doesn't turn on and just blinks initially.

Comment: Note that when I connect the LED directly to the 5v+resistor it also turns it on so no sure whats going on.

Comment: Diode connected transistors have lots of uses so I also disagree with the "no practical use" part. For example they are commonly used as temperature sensors.

Comment: Steady on, guys. I didn't say "no practical use". I try to pitch answers a little above the level the OP is at. In this case s/he's trying to turn on an LED. It'll be a while before we're answering questions about analog transistor circuits.